# Session/ Temp data Strategy for related data with asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a entry page with a list of companies.

The companies view has an open button doing a redirect to the Departments index view with the attached companyId because that is needed to display the Departments for this company:

```
 public IActionResult OpenCompany(int id)
 {
return RedirectToRoute(new { Controller = "Departments", Action = "Index", CompanyId = id });
 }
```

Now my Departments Index view with all existing departments is displayed.

Over that table is a `"Create Department"` button. But I can not create that Department because I need that CompanyId.

How do I get that CompanyId ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass this information (company id) to your index action and use that as needed.

Add a new property to your department index action's view model

```
public class DepartmentIndexVm
{
  public int? CompanyIdCameFrom { set;get;}
  // Add Other properties for the index action as needed
}
```

Now in your Department index action,

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
  var vm = new DepartmentIndexVm { CompanyIdCameFrom = id }); 
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now in the department index view, simply use this `CompanyIdCameFrom` property value when you create the "Create department" link/button

```
@model DepartmentIndexVm
<a asp-action="create" asp-controller="department"
                                  asp-route-companyId="@Model.CompanyIdCameFrom">Create</a>
```

Assuming your `create` action method accepts a `companyId` parameter

```
public ActionResult Create(int? companyId)
{
  // to do  : return something
}
```

If you do not prefer the view model approach, you might consider using ViewBag. Instead of setting to the view model property, set to ViewBag and use that when building the link.

Comment: one reason more to use viewmodels not the EF pocos like MS is doing in their stupid minimalistic mvc tuts ;-)

Comment: Yea. Try to not use the Entity classes generated by EF/Any ORM tool in your UI layer. That makes it tightly coupled to that data access technology. If you decide to change your data access layer to a faster one tomorrow, you will not be affected big time, because your UI does not have tight coupling to that, but to the view models. You just need to update the mapping from entities to view models (when reading data)